# How can i loop over Tree in ZK?

Tags: zk

I try to get the values of the ZK Tree from [this](https://www.zkoss.org/zkdemo/tree/dynamic_tree) example. But i not get the all childrens value...what i tried:

```
    List<Treechildren> treeChildren = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Label> labelList = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Label> childs = new ArrayList<>();

    tree.getChildren().forEach(component -> {
        if(component instanceof Treechildren){
            treeChildren.add((Treechildren) component);
        }
    });
    List<Treeitem> treeItems = new ArrayList<>();
    treeChildren.forEach(treechildren ->{
        treeItems.addAll(treechildren.getChildren());           
    });
    List<Treechildren> children = new ArrayList<>();

    treeItems.forEach(treeitem -> {
        System.err.println("treeitem: " + treeitem);
        if (treeitem.getChildren().size() > 1) {    
            treeitem.getChildren().forEach(child -> {
                if(child instanceof Treechildren){
                    children.add((Treechildren) child);
                } else {
                    List<Treecell> tcList = new ArrayList<>();
                    child.getChildren().forEach(component -> { 
                        if(component instanceof Treecell) {
                            tcList.add((Treecell) component);
                        }
                    });
                    List<Hlayout> hlList = new ArrayList<>();
                    tcList.forEach(treecell ->{
                        System.err.println("treecell" + treecell);
                        hlList.addAll(treecell.getChildren());
                    });

                    hlList.forEach(hlayout -> {
                        childs.addAll(hlayout.getChildren());
                    });

                }
            });
        }else {

            List<Treerow> tr = new ArrayList<>();
            treeitem.getChildren().forEach(component -> {
                if (component instanceof Treerow) {
                    tr.add((Treerow) component);
                } else {
                }

            });
            List<Treecell> TC = new ArrayList<>();
            tr.forEach(treerow -> {
                TC.addAll(treerow.getChildren());
            });

            List<Hlayout> HL = new ArrayList<>();
            TC.forEach(treecell -> {
                HL.addAll(treecell.getChildren());
            });

            HL.forEach(hlayout -> labelList.addAll(hlayout.getChildren()));
        }
    });

    labelList.forEach(label -> System.err.println("label: " + label.getValue()));
    childs.forEach(label -> System.err.println("childs: " + label.getValue()));
}
```

But i not get the whole tree labels....the aim is to save the tree to database when i push the submit button.

Answer (score 1):

Since you did not post your tree, I can only guess how it looks. But I tried to at least understand your code and found a potential bug: In line 21 handle the case where tree nodes have sub nodes. You add the Treechildren to `children`, but never do anything with it. So you loop will stop at the first level.

First of all, I would recommend using the special methods for trees and their components:

- Tree: getTreechildren()
- Treeitem: getTree(), getTreerow() and getTreechildren()
- Treerow: getTree() and getLinkedTreechildren()

These help you to get rid of all the casting and instanceof checks. Furthermore, you can specify the type of children when calling `getChildren()`:

```
List<Treecell> cells = row.<Treecell> getChildren()
```

Now you don't have to cast, but to be careful that all children are of the same type.

Finally, I refactored your code to understand it:

```
// Find all items in the tree, level by level
List<Treeitem> items = new ArrayList<>(tree.getTreechildren().getChildren());
List<Treeitem> itemsTemp = new ArrayList<>(tree.getTreechildren().getChildren());
while (!itemsTemp.isEmpty())
{
    Treeitem nextChild = itemsTemp.remove(0);
    if (nextChild.getTreechildren() != null)
    {
        items.addAll(nextChild.getTreechildren().getChildren());
        itemsTemp.addAll(nextChild.getTreechildren().getChildren());
    }
}

// convert item -> row -> cells -> hlayouts -> children
List<Component> children = items.stream()
                                .map(Treeitem::getTreerow)
                                .filter(Objects::nonNull)
                                .flatMap(row -> row.<Treecell> getChildren().stream())
                                .flatMap(cell -> cell.<Hlayout> getChildren().stream())
                                .flatMap(hlayout -> hlayout.getChildren().stream())
                                .collect(Collectors.toList());

    // // without streams
    // List<Component> children = new ArrayList<>();
    // for (Treeitem item : items)
    // {
    //     if (item.getTreerow() != null)
    //     {
    //         for (Treecell cell : item.getTreerow().<Treecell> getChildren())
    //         {
    //             for (Hlayout hlayout : cell.<Hlayout> getChildren())
    //             {
    //                 children.addAll(hlayout.getChildren());
    //             }
    //         }
    //     }
    // }
```

You can see that in the while loop, I looked at the tree's children on the first level, then at their children, that at those children's children, and so on. Then I used the methods mentioned above to find the components of each tree node.

Again, I do not know how your tree looks, so I do not know whether this works for you. Maybe you could post a small example.